# How to show a Google Maps heatmap in WordPress admin?

Tags: wordpress, maps, heatmap

I have built a WordPress website to be used as an admin only interface. I have grabbed a Google Maps API key and copied the example code from the tutorials at:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap

I have copied the code provided by Google into an admin page template but nothing is showing. When I inspect the page content I can see that extra styling is added:

`<div id="map" style="position: relative;overflow: hidden;">`

If I turn off either of those stylings I can see the map appear but it does not fit at all even if specific heights and widths are defined.

I wondered if anyone else has had any luck trying to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it wasn't the css addition at all, it was that the map div needed to have the height defined in pixels instead of percentage!